# Twitter API tweets for time range

Tags: api, twitter

Is there a way to use the Twitter API to get a user's tweets for a specific time range?

It doesn't seem to be in statuses/user_timeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `since` and `until` operator.

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&inc‌​lude_rts=true&screen_name=your_screen_name&since:2011-05-16&until:2011-08-16`

But it will do you little good because tweets are searchable in a small time window. To get around this check out several resources,

Snapbird - https://github.com/remy/snapbird

and

[20 ways of searching old tweets](http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/)

Comment: Adding since and until doesn't do anything. user_timeline still just returns all the most recent tweets.

Comment: it's a search operator, so it may be applicable in that context. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search . Also, please accept some answers. Thanks.

Comment: twitter rest v1 api is gone, 1.1 might be active.

Comment: edited answer for 1.1 , unfortunately one needs to authenticate this request now.

Comment: ur links are all broken now