# Python Twitter search.tweets with until

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am using Python Twitter search api from https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter

When I try to search for a query using the "until" parameter, the search does not return anything

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(....))

t.search.tweets(q = 'hello', count=3, until='2012-01-01')
{u'search_metadata': {u'count': 3, u'completed_in': 0.007, u'max_id_str': u'9223372036854775807', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=9223372036854775807&q=hello%20until%3A2012-01-01&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'hello+until%3A2012-01-01', u'max_id': 9223372036854775807L}, u'statuses': []}
```

while when I search without "until", it finds tweets normally. When I try the search manually on twitter.com/search

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=hello%20until%3A2012-01-01&src=typd
```

it also finds tweets normally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all about twitter api search limitations. Quote from [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search):

> You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week

For example, try running

```
print t.search.tweets(q='hello', count=3, until='2013-03-01')
```

and you'll see results.

Also, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655403/twitter-api-tweets-for-time-range).