# How do I fetch n tweets before and after a specific tweet?

Tags: web-services, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to fetch `n` tweets by a user that occurred BEFORE a particular tweet by that same user and `n` tweets that occurred AFTER. For example, if I know of a particular tweet `t` by user `u`, then for `n = 50`, I want to fetch the 50 tweets that led up to t and the 50 that occurred right after `t`. `GET statuses/user_timeline` lets me fetch tweets for a user from their timeline and I suppose I could use `max_id` to specify the `ID` of tweet `t` such that the 50 prior to t would be fetched, but I can't figure out how to get the 50 that followed `t`. since_id, obviously, won't help.

Is this even possible? If so, how should I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655403/twitter-api-tweets-for-time-range

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the right answer didn't show up there. One idea suggested there is to use "since" and "until," which I've used before, but those are for searching tweets within a timeframe; they 1) don't allow specifying a range by tweet count and 2) aren't usable for searching a particular tweeter's tweets. There was a link posted that seemed promising, but the page doesn't exist anymore.

Thanks, though!

Comment: I dont think the exact feature you're looking for is available

Comment: I'm afraid that's my finding too so far.