# how to change the period of popular tweets to get?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using this link to get popular tweets (in English for example)

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=('[]')&lang=en&result_type=popular&count=100
```

But it GETs the popular tweets in current week. Because of this, the result of it is repetitious! If you see its result ever and ever in one day, the same tweets you will see!
but how can I change the period of it? for example just GET the popular tweets since yesterday?
I tried to use since ID field but it's Non-variable.
I'm using PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter API tweets for time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655403/twitter-api-tweets-for-time-range)

Comment: It doesn't work in Twitter Search Api